# what is the difference between ++, add operation and fetch_add() in atomic()

Tags: c++, c++11

I ran following code many times but why the result for   prefix increment , fetch_add() shows the correct result  while with add operation (+), it  prints the wrong result?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <mutex>
#include <future>
using namespace std;
atomic <int> cnt (0);
void fun()
{
    for(int i =0; i <10000000 ; ++i)
    {
       //++cnt; // print the correct result 20000000 
       //cnt = cnt+1; // print wrong result, arbitrary numbers 
       cnt.fetch_add(1); //  print the correct result 20000000 
    }
}
int main()
{
    auto fut1 = async(std::launch::async, fun);
    auto fut2 = async(std::launch::async, fun);
    fut1.get();
    fut2.get();
    cout << "value of cnt: "<<cnt <<endl;

}
```

Answer (score 32, accepted):

`++cnt` and `cnt.fetch_add(1)` are truly atomic operations.  One thread is blocked while the other thread reads, increments, and updates the value. As such, the two threads cannot step on each other's toes.  Access to `cnt` is fully serialized, and the final result is as you would expect.

`cnt = cnt+1;` is not fully atomic.  It involves three separate operations, only two of which are atomic, but one is not.  By the time a thread has atomically read the current value of `cnt` and made a *copy* of it locally, the other thread is no longer blocked and can freely modify `cnt` at will while that *copy* is being incremented.  Then, the assignment of the incremented *copy* back to `cnt` is done atomically, but will be assigning a stale value if `cnt` has already been modified by the other thread.  So the final result is random and not what you would expect.

Comment: According to the standard `cnt.fetch_add(1)` is equivalent to `cnt++`.

Comment: @CAF doesn't matter in this case. `cnt.fetch_add(1)` is still a single atomic operation, as is `cnt++`. The code is not acting on the return value.

Answer (score 12):

`cnt = cnt+1`

This is not an atomic operation. This first loads `cnt` in one atomic operation, then does the addition and finally stores the result in another atomic operation. However, the value can be changed after loading which can be overwritten by final store which leads to wrong end result.

The other two are atomic operations and thus avoid such race condition.

Note that, operator `++, --, +=, -=, &=, |=, ^=` are overloaded in `std::atomic` to provide atomic operations.

Answer (score 0):

operator ++ is not a single operation but 3 operations load add store, and for ex on arm64 single load or store dosn't generate any data fence, data memory barier.
for ex atomic_add 1 is a bunch of code with aquire/release semantics

```
.LBB2_1:            
ldaxr   x8, [x0] //load exclusive register with aquire 
add x8, x8, #1  
stlxr   w9, x8, [x0] //store with rlease
cbnz    w9, .LBB2_1 //if another thread changed value, try again
```

where operator ++ will cause race condition if simulateusly used by 2 threads

```
ldr x8, [x0]
add x8, x8, #1              // =1
str x8, [x0]
```

Comment: Are you talking about `operator++` of `std::atomic`? It is supposed to be atomic. E. g. GCC compiles both `++` and `fetch_add` to `lock add` on amd64.

Comment: Not just supposed to be, guaranteed. It's even "more" atomic than it needs to be since it is defined as equivalent to `fetch_add(1)+1`. Which is, lacking a memory order specification, sequentially consistent (although relaxed would almost certainly do fine). See https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/atomic/atomic/operator_arith

Comment: i missed that dissucion is about atomic<int> and not an just int increment, my fault

Comment: and atomic<>::operator ++ gives exactly same code as fetch_add
.LBB0_1:                               
 ldaxr x0, [x8]
 add x9, x0, #1              
 stlxr w10, x9, [x8]
 cbnz w10, .LBB0_1